Why was my flag declined?
I flagged this question because it seemed to be a definition question, and it appears that my flag for it was declined. Why was that the case?

I would've chosen to close it. It's a simple lookup in a dictionary. There is no effort shown whatsoever in either looking up the word or learning Chinese.

@deutschZuid: I don't have enough rep at this point to submit close votes.

It looks like three users did not agree that this question was off-topic so the close flag was declined.
Based on the vulgar word and the user's behaviour on other sites, I assume this question was posted as a joke, so I'm closing it. If anyone thinks it was a useful question, you can vote to reopen.
